# Are all subgroups of the fundamental group of a compact smooth manifold finitely generated?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology

And if not, is there a way to assign a size to a subgroup by considering the compactness of the corresponding covering space?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that every finitely presented group is $\pi_1$ of a smooth compact manifold? Also, what do you think is the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1$ of a compact surface of genus $\ge 2$?

Comment: This might be a helpful link for you as well http://mathoverflow.net/questions/192230/is-there-a-manifold-with-fundamental-group-mathbbq